# How to Import Blender 2.79 built-in matcaps to Blender 2.80?

Tags: sculpting, matcaps

I'm missing my favorite matcap from Blender 2.79 in 2.80, this one on the left, indicated with a blue border:

[image: Blender 2.79 matcaps]

Is there a way to extract matcaps from 2.79 and import them into 2.80? Or maybe there is a repository of old matcaps as images, somewhere in the Blender git?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OP's comment [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/127351/how-to-import-blender-2-79-built-in-matcaps-to-blender-2-80#comment220706_127353) reminded me that you could probably check the `v2.79` tag (i.e. release) to find these files.

Here they are on the official repository:

https://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender.git/tree/v2.79:/release/datafiles/matcaps

Here they are on the GitHub mirror:

https://github.com/blender/blender/tree/v2.79/release/datafiles/matcaps

The one you're looking for looks like [Matcap 9](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/v2.79/release/datafiles/matcaps/mc09.jpg):

[image]

Comment: Good call! I've mentioned your suggestions too now

Comment: Good idea, mine was slightly less convenient - download the whole archive and extract those files, eg. from there https://download.blender.org/source/blender-2.79b.tar.gz

Answer (score 3):

If I remember correctly, matcaps in 2.79 weren't exr, which should mean that they were basically *defined* by their own preview image.

So what I'd do is:

- take a screenshot of B2.79 (as you have already done)
- cut just the matcap:

  [image]

  (( **or better: use the actual 2.79 jpegs as [Moira suggests](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/127381/16395)!** ))
- save it (e.g. with GIMP) as an `.exr`
- place it in the Blender folder, under `2.80/datafiles/studiolights/matcaps`
- *voila*

  [image]

Comment: Thanks, I got another idea after some searching on blender git, the main problem was the "master" is now a 2.8 so I couldn't find those files there, but I found them elsewhere, maybe I will publish that as another answer later.